# How to generate sentences in char-level chatbot?

Tags: python, tensorflow, chatbot, tflearn

I am trying to implement a char-based Chatbot in Turkish. I am using TFLearn's text generation example on this [link](https://github.com/tflearn/tflearn/blob/master/examples/nlp/lstm_generator_shakespeare.py).

I edited the `string_to_semi_redundant_sequences` function, since I want to create a chatbot. Originally, this model produces single char for a sequence of chars, so X keeps one-hot-vector of char-sequences of each input sentence and Y keeps one-hot-vector of a single char corresponds to those sequences. I changed the function into this:

```
    def my_string_to_semi_redundant_sequences(inputs, targets, 
                                      seq_maxlen, char_idx):

      print('Vectorizing text...')

      len_chars = len(char_idx)

      X = numpy.zeros((len(inputs), seq_maxlen, len_chars), dtype=numpy.bool)
      Y = numpy.zeros((len(targets), seq_maxlen, len_chars), dtype=numpy.bool)

      for i, seq in enumerate(inputs):
        for t in range(seq_maxlen):

          if(seq[t] != '0'):
            X[i, t, char_idx[seq[t]]] = 1

          if(targets[i][t] != '0'):
            Y[i, t, char_idx[targets[i][t]]] = 1

      Y = Y.reshape([-1, seq_maxlen*len_chars ])

      print('Text vectorized.')
      print('Total sequences  : {:,}'.format(len(targets)))
      print('Distinct chars   : {:,}'.format(len_chars))

      return X, Y
```

As you can see, my Y keeps more than one one-hot-encoded char. It keeps the target(sentence) for corresponding input(can be considered Question-Response). And I reshaped Y into `[batch_size, seq_maxlen*len_chars]` by thinking the model will produce "seq_maxlen" chars to form a sentence. And here is the details of  my model:

```
    maxlen = 50

    X, Y = my_string_to_semi_redundant_sequences(inputs, targets, 
                                         maxlen, char_idx)
    q = tflearn.input_data([None, maxlen, len(char_idx)])
    q = tflearn.lstm(q, 128, return_seq=True)
    q = tflearn.dropout(q, 0.2)
    q = tflearn.lstm(q, 128, return_seq=True)
    q = tflearn.dropout(q, 0.2)
    q = tflearn.lstm(q, 128)
    q = tflearn.dropout(q, 0.2)

    q = tflearn.fully_connected(q, maxlen*len(char_idx), activation='softmax')
    q = tflearn.regression(q, optimizer='adam', 
                           loss='categorical_crossentropy', 
                           learning_rate=0.001)

    m = tflearn.SequenceGenerator(q, dictionary=char_idx, 
                                  seq_maxlen=maxlen, 
                                  clip_gradients=5.0,  
                                  checkpoint_path='model_mentalist')
    m.fit(X, Y, validation_set=0.1, batch_size=32, n_epoch=500, 
  run_id='mentalist', snapshot_epoch=False, snapshot_step=2000)
```

The length of my char dictionary is 94. And since I want model to produce 50(maxlen) chars, I set the number of units `maxlen*len(char_idx)` in `fully_connected_layer`.

I trained the model for around 2000 steps, just make sure everything is OK. And I wanted to see some result. But when I tried to generate a response with:

```
    m.generate(maxlen, temperature=0.5, seq_seed=string))
```

I got this error:

```
    KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
    <ipython-input-9-fbc4c70d085d> in <module>()
          5   string = input('Sen: ')
          6   if string != 'çıkış':
    ----> 7     print('Jane: ' + m.generate(50, temperature=0.5, seq_seed=string))

    /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tflearn/models/generator.py in generate(self, seq_length, temperature, seq_seed, display)
        216             preds = self._predict(x)[0].tolist()
        217             next_index = _sample(preds, temperature)
    --> 218             next_char = self.rev_dic[next_index]
        219 
        220             try: #Python 2

    KeyError: 3274
```

I think it has something to do with the dimensions of my inputs(X and Y) and the dimension of fully_connected_layer. Because when I tried to reshape Y into `[-1,len(char_idx)]` and set the `n_units` of `fully_connected_layer` to `len(char_idx)` I got no error but the results seemed very bad even with more than 40.000 training steps.

So can you help me see what I've been doing wrong?

Thank you.